# Выбрать несколько элементов внутри одного класса

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, htmlagilitypack, anglesharp

```
  <div>
    <div class="match__teams">
      <div class="team__info">
        <div class="team__title">IG.V</div>
        <div class="team__coeff">x1.31</div>
      </div>
      <div class="team__info">
        <div class="team__title">IG.V</div>
        <div class="team__coeff">x1.31</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="match__teams">
      <div class="team__info">
        <div class="team__title">Na`Vi</div>
        <div class="team__coeff">x1.90</div>
      </div>
      <div class="team__info">
        <div class="team__title">Gambit</div>
        <div class="team__coeff">x1.3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Нужно из `class="match__teams` выбрать `team__title` обоих команд, чтобы в итоге можно было записать их в виде Team1 vs Team2 в строку. Далее с новой строки эти же значения из другого блока `class="match__teams` в таком же виде Team1 vs Team 2. Блоков `class="match__teams` много. Итоговый вид должен быть примерно таким:

1. Team1 vs Team2
2. Team1 vs Team2
3. Team1 vs Team

Где Team1 это первый title из блока, и Team2 это второй title из этого же блока.

Comment: @AK Добавил изменения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, во-первых, вы пишете в скриптовом стиле - не разделяете фазу сбора информации и вывода информации.

По-хорошему нужно описать форматы данных, например:

```
// Информация о матче
public class MatchInfo
{
    public TeamInfo Team1 { get; set; }
    public TeamInfo Team2 { get; set; }
}

// Информация о команде
public class TeamInfo
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Koef { get; set; }
}
```

Либо скажем такой, упрощённый:

```
// Информация о матче
public class MatchInfo
{
    public string Team1 { get; set; }
    public string Team1Koef { get; set; }
    public string Team2 { get; set; }
    public string Team2Koef { get; set; }
}
```

Заполнить её, а потом уже вывести.

Допустим, ваши данные такие:

```
public IDocument GetSampleData()
{
    var html = @"
<div>
    <div class=""match__teams"">
      <div class=""team__info"">
        <div class=""team__title"">IG.V</div>
        <div class=""team__coeff"">x1.31</div>
      </div>
      <div class=""team__info"">
        <div class=""team__title"">IG.V</div>
        <div class=""team__coeff"">x1.31</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class=""match__teams"">
      <div class=""team__info"">
        <div class=""team__title"">Na`Vi</div>
        <div class=""team__coeff"">x1.90</div>
      </div>
      <div class=""team__info"">
        <div class=""team__title"">Gambit</div>
        <div class=""team__coeff"">x1.3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>";

    var parser = new HtmlParser();
    var document = parser.Parse(html);
    return document;
}
```

Парсим:

```
public MatchInfo[] ParseData(IDocument document)
{
    var result = new List<MatchInfo>();
    var matches = document.QuerySelectorAll(".match__teams");
    foreach (var element in matches)
    {
        var teams = element.QuerySelectorAll(".team__info");

        if (teams.Count() != 2)
            throw new Exception("Вот сейчас неожиданно было");

        var team1 = teams[0];
        var team2 = teams[1];

        var match = new MatchInfo
        {
            Team1 = new TeamInfo { Title = team1.Children[0].TextContent, Koef = team1.Children[1].TextContent },
            Team2 = new TeamInfo { Title = team2.Children[0].TextContent, Koef = team2.Children[1].TextContent },
        };
        result.Add(match);
    }
    return result.ToArray();
}
```

Выводим:

```
public void ShowData(MatchInfo[] data)
{
    foreach (var match in data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{match.Team1.Title} vs {match.Team2.Title}");
    }
}
```

Итого:

```
var document = GetSampleData();
var data = ParseData(document);
ShowData(data);
```

Выведет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это если вы уверены, что структура именно такая. Жесткость этого кода можно снизить:

```
    var team1 = teams[0].QuerySelectorAll(".team__title").FirstOrDefault();
    var team2 = teams[1].QuerySelectorAll(".team__title").FirstOrDefault();

    var match = new MatchInfo
    {
        Team1 = new TeamInfo { Title = team1.TextContent, Koef = team1.TextContent },
        Team2 = new TeamInfo { Title = team2.TextContent, Koef = team2.TextContent },
    };
```

Или так:

```
    var team1 = teams[0].QuerySelector(".team__title");
    var team2 = teams[1].QuerySelector(".team__title");

    var match = new MatchInfo
    {
        Team1 = new TeamInfo { Title = team1.TextContent, Koef = team1.TextContent },
        Team2 = new TeamInfo { Title = team2.TextContent, Koef = team2.TextContent },
    };
```

Чистенько, аккуратненько, циклов немного, код наглядный и понятный.

Comment: Спасибо большое еще раз. Вижу, что работает 100%, но у меня пока что не заводится. Ищу проблему.